# Templates not showing up in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 (Community). I'm trying to create a bot by using a template in C#.

I added the zip folder (the template) to C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C# and I'm trying to open it up by creating a new project.

The template doesn't show up at all.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart VS?

Comment: I did, yes. Same issue. I was thinking to unzip and open up the template in Visual Studio and continue editing for the purposes of my project as opposed to creating a new Project. Not sure if this would work though. (Newbie here) Thanks very much.

Comment: I looked into it a bit more and I scrolled down to Online Templates / C# (as opposed to Installed Templates / C#) in Visual Studio 2017 and I found the Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio. I am hoping this is the right one, I will give this a try. The guidance I was using was suggesting to find the template under Installed Templates.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got that to work  on my side.
How .....
after 5 hrs of trying.... and searching the web i did:

1. **Upgraded to latest version** of  Visual Studio Community 2017 with the installer in 
   control panel.
2. **Did a Repair** of Visual Studio Community 2017 with the installer in control panel.
3. **Then opened any C# project** i had on hand and proceed with the **export Template wizard.**

   - check : *Automatically import the template into Visual Studio*
   - check : *Display an explorer window on the output files folder*

then waited.....
then windows explorer opened with this path:

> E:\Users\bern\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates

with a zip file in it !!!! **MYTESTTEMPLATE.ZIP** just created

Then i when to the path

- e:\Users\bern\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates
  listed in Visual studio  TOOL/OPTION/Projects and solutions/Location

user project Templates location:

> **e:\Users\bern\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates**

I saw again the zip files

> MYTESTTEMPLATE.ZIP

4. closed Visual Studio , re opened Visual studio
5. **BINGO!** the template was listed under Visual C#

PS : sorry if it`s a marathon but it worked.

From there i proved to myself that it did at least worked with the wizard.

Now, for a template created manually from me just ZIPED and pasted in

> **user project Templates location: e:\Users\bern\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates**

why it is not showing ???? continuing my investigation....

Then i managed to associate the file type *.vstemplate to open in Visual studio 2017.
Opened both *.vstemplate file ( the test one and my manual one) to compare elements.

I did some cut and paste from the wizard template file into the manual template file just to make sure.

1. Saved and zipped the manual template .
2. copied the zip file in

   > ** e:\Users\bern\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates**
   >   and copied in 
   >   E:\Users\bern\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates
3. closed visual studio, open visual studio with a solution X.
4. clicked ADD new Project

AND there it was , at the bottom of the list !!!! the template created with the wizard and **my manual template created by hand**... OUFFF.....

I could have maybe  just said ....

copy your zip template in

> ** e:\Users*YOU*\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates**
>   and 
>   E:\Users*YOU*\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates

but it would not have given the process of investigation i when through .

I hope it will help some of you guys.

Thank you

Comment: by the way i did not yet removed the wizard created template in case i loose the other one... just been scared. 
i will try that tomorrow ;).