# create my template installer from Visual Studio installer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a standard application that i customize by client. 
each time i deploy i have to create am MSI for that client.

Each time i create a Setup Project from the Visual Studio Installer.
then i have a lot of parameter that are the same ex: manufacturer, company, icon etc.

I tried and tried and wonder if it is Possible to create my own Project Template from the Setup Project of Visual Studio Installer.

Note: I use Visual Studio 2017 Community .
      the export Template is disabled in the project menu.
    I tried openning VS in Admin mode.
i tried to temper the *.vstemplate file....

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello please refer to my answer in

[Templates not showing up in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638558/templates-not-showing-up-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2017?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I created a Setup projet with in the same solution of my main project programme.
i did all the configuration standard for the setup.
Saved everything.
placed that project in the same location of the *vstemplate file created manualy.
Edited the *vstemplate file in visual studio to add element

```
<TemplateContent>
<Project File="SysBSetup.vdproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
</Project>
```

ZIPPED everything and did all the manipulation described in the other post.

Is it perfect , no but its very helpfull!

i'm open to other solution.

Thank you

Comment: well it looks like its more complicated then that ....
i'm now investigating Visual studio extensibility.....
more to come...